# Округление до определенных разрядов си

Tags: c, round

В данном задании вам необходимо написать тело функции is_in, которая определит попадание точки в закрашенную область.

На вход функция получает два числа х и у. Эти числа имеют точность 10−5" data-math-display-mode="false" role="region" tabindex="-1">10−5  , т.е. числа, у которых не больше четырех знаков после запятой.

Функция должна вывести строку "true", если точка попадает в заштрихованную область или попадает на границу, строку "false" - в противном случае.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код, не могу понять почему округление не работает и компилятор просто заканчивает программу с 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void is_in(float x, float y) 
{
    if (x*x+y*y>=1 && x>1 && y>1)
    printf("true");
    else
    printf("false");
}

int main ()
{
    float x,y;
    scanf("%f%f", &x, &y);
    x= roundf(x*10000)/10000;
    y= roundf(y*10000)/10000;
    is_in(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит *"компилятор просто заканчивает программу с 1"*?

Comment: Как минимум условие ` if (x*x+y*y>=1 && x>1 && y>1)` неверное. Сами подумайте...

Comment: @Harry, да, x и y лишние, но не играют особой роли. Почему не работает округление, если сначала вводятся значения для двух переменных, а потом передаются в функцию? Я очень чайник в си.

Comment: @Green Joker округление у вас сделано правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (x * x + y * y >= 1 && abs(x) <= 1 && abs(y) <= 1)
```

Если надо чтобы `true` выводила только для правого - верхнего угла то:

```
if (x * x + y * y >= 1 && x <= 1 && y <= 1 && x > 0 && y > 0)
```

Comment: только надо `y * y`

Comment: @Zhihar все исправил

Comment: во втором примере `abs`  можно было бы и не писать, а просто `x <= 1 && y <= 1` дальше же все равно с `> 0` сравнивается, да и надо бы `x*x + y*y >= 1` - вроде бы окружность все таки входит

Answer (score 2):

То есть так?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void is_in(float x, float y) 
{
    if (x * x + y * y >= 1 && x <= 1 && y <= 1 && x > 0 && y > 0) 
    printf("true");
    else
    printf("false");
}

int main ()
{
    float x,y;
    scanf("%f%f", &x, &y);
    x=roundf(x*10000)/10000;
    y=roundf(y*10000)/10000;
    is_in(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да  именно так и надо